# Hyperlinks not loading page but showing selected

Tags: asp.net-core, hyperlink, blazor-server-side

ASP,net core3.0 Server-side Blazor application. After selecting a link in a page. The selected page does not load, however the name shows in the address bar. I have to click "refresh" in the browser to make the page load.

I tried changing the Home page links from "" to "/" and finally added a second page directive to the Home page of "/Home" and added that.

Everything loads in the development environment just fine. But in Azure, it reacts like this.

The Nav menu is the same as the template, I even left the weather page as I want to actually use this later.

```
<div class="top-row pl-4 navbar navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
        <h1 id="Title">SHOP LIVE</h1>
        <h6 id="Title">Version 2.0</h6>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" onclick="@ToggleNavMenu">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
</div>

<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" onclick="@ToggleNavMenu">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/Home" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Repair Orders
            </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/ShopMap">
                <span class="oi oi-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span> Shop Map
            </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="fetchdata">
                <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Weather
            </NavLink>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

@functions {
    bool collapseNavMenu = true;

    string NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }
}
```

---Update---

I am getting the error:

> cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'connected' state

in the browser console.  I am finding this on Google, but everyone says this was fixed in a previous preview version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server-side Blazor uses web-sockets (through SignalR) for the communication between the server and the browser.

Web sockets are disabled by default in Azure web-apps, I think that's why your browser can't connect to server.

Go to your Azure App configuration to enable web sockets.

Doc : [Publish an ASP.NET Core SignalR app to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/publish-to-azure-web-app?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configure-the-app-in-azure-app-service)

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it.  Now to find out why the stupid data binding is now failing. I don't think it is related to this issue and it is doing it both in development and on the production site.